# Unable to Connect to Azure SQL-Server: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, mssql-jdbc

Created an Azure SQL server machine and I am able to rdp as well as connect via the local SQL Server Mgt Studio client.

However I cannot connect to the same instance via Java code using the connection string further below.

- I am using  the latest JDBC Driver (Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.4)
- I am using SQL Server 2017 Express
- I am able to connect manually via SQL Server Mgt Studio client on local machine

Here is the error message:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
>   establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption. Error:
>   "sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target".
>   ClientConnectionId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Here is the connection string:

> jdbc:sqlserver://Server=nn.nnn.nnn.nnn;Integrated Security=false;User
>   ID=myusername;Password=mypassword

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by changing in the connection string:

```
encrypt=true
```

**into**

```
encrypt=false
```

Not sure this is the best solution but at least I can carry on developement.

Comment: @LeonYue I dont believe this is the best solution. This is why I have not marked it as the accepted solution.

Comment: unfortunately the project is abandoned as the new direction is Python

Comment: If you are working on your localhost is fine - else do the right thing with the cert.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by the driver not finding a certificate that it trusts. If you do have a relevant certificate installed and are working on your localhost (meaning that it's probably self-signed and therefore wouldn't be trusted otherwise), try adding this to the end of your connection string:
`trustServerCertificate=true`

If it's a different machine you're working on, you may need to take a look at the validity of the certificate that it should be using.

Microsoft also now has more information about SSL connections to SQL Server [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption).